# Python - Error when running the 'help()' command outside of the interpreter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am starting out playing around with Python and trying to understand how to navigate it.

I noticed that in the regular command line (Power shell) I can at times run a python command like 'python -m ABC' and it executes just fine.

I recently learned about the "help()" function within the Python interpreter so for example I would type help('modules') to display all the installed modules.

When I try to execute in the command line 'python -m help('modules')' I get an error saying "No module named help" but I literally can run it in the interpreter.

This is a totally low level question but just curious why do I get this error?

Comment: The flag to run a single command is `-c`, not `-m`.

Comment: -m says run module, help is not a module but a function you have to tell python to run it as code -c

Comment: differences are here : https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-c 
You should have ran `python -c "help('modules')"`. `-m` implies a module as mentioned in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`help` isn't a module; it's a callable class. To execute code, (which can include a call to a function/callable), you want `-c`:

```
python -c 'help(print)'
```

Comment: nitpick: it's not a function

Comment: @wim Today I learned. Updated.

Comment: @Carcigenicate - Curious - Why does the command have to have the word 'modules' in quotes vs your example uses the word print with no quotes?

Comment: @rodneyc8063 Because `print` is the name of a function in Python. Names don't requires quotes. `modules` is a string, not a name of an object, and strings use quotes.